# How to convert videos by looping from the directory to images using ffmpeg?

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, command-line-interface, video-conversion

I'm learning how to do image video conversion using ffmpeg. I know how to convert from 1 video to several frames, but which commands to use to convert several videos into frames?

Answer (score 0):

Let assume your images are placed in `tmp` directory and the file names are "1.jpg, 2.jpg, ...."

Then you can use this command

```
ffmpeg -r [fps] -i tmp/%d.jpg -vcodec mpeg4 -y [video_name]
```

Comment: No, I have many .mp4 files in the directory and want to extract them into images, not create video from frames. Like this one from documentation `ffmpeg -i foo.avi -r 1 -s WxH -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg` but instead, loop for several videos.

Comment: Why don't use python?
`import os`
`os.system("ffmpeg -i {0} -r 1 -s WxH -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg".format(file_name)`

You can loop files in the directory easily

Comment: I just want to know how to do it in CLI, but I think I will use python. Thanks for your suggestion :)